# Is there a plugin for posting inline comments, like in MS Word?

Tags: plugins, comments

I want to make a cookbook style wordpress website, on which visitors can place comments inline. Like you do in a paper book with a pen: between the lines. Or like how MS Word handles comments.

Does anyone know a plugin that makes this possible? I've searched and searched, but all I found was this and it was of no use:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196993/wordpress-having-comments-inline-ajax-like-in-stackoverflow

I don't get it to work and the developers page is nothing more than a logo.

Comment: The linked Q/A doesn't do what you want to have.

Comment: After thinking a while about it: No, this is simply not possible. If you'd really try to do this, then it would add a major performance hit, as you'd have to count a lot, interact with single DOM elements, etc. IMHO you should leave this idea behind. +1 anyway for a nice "not in this world"-idea :)

Comment: Thanks Kaiser! I'm now thinking of doing it manually: Visitors can post normal comments and if they're worth sharing inline, the authors can copy the text and paste it in the post. My original idea can be simulated with a custom styled div for this copied text, that can be made with a customized tinyMCE button.

Comment: Shortcode + comment ID would be a way to go. Aggree.

Comment: Try using this javascript plugin Its independent and fast
Annote js ( http://annote.in )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plugin with that readers can post comments inline, like in Microsoft Word.

The WordPress plugin bases on [inlineDisqussions](http://tsi.github.io/inlineDisqussions/) by Tsi and is called Inline Comments:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/inline-comments/

Inline Comments adds the great Disqus Comment System to the side of paragraphs and other specific sections (like headlines and images) of your post.

Comment: Outstanding. Suggestion for future development: make the comment system independent from Disqus if possible.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want to do, definitely! Thanks :)

Comment: @ChristineCooper: I updated my plugin. Now Inline Comments performs **independent** from Disqus! Have a look: http://kevinw.de/inline-comments

Comment: That is, in every possible way, brilliant! How about performance? Does this plugin perform well when considering server performances? Is it running many more queries than because each paragraph has its on comment area etc?

Comment: It performs great. The plugin does not request additional comments "per paragraph". The plugin uses the native WordPress comments that are already loaded when someone calls an article page. The comments will be requested onetime and then displayed "hidden" or "visible" next to each paragraph (using jQuery).

Comment: Great to hear. How about general theme integration? Can you reply to a comment? Finally, can you add a feature where admin can select who is allowed to comment AND who is allowed to see the comments? Personally, I would love to add this as a way for editors to leave comments on paragraphs for editorial purposes, not to be displayed to the public... Nonetheless, this plugin has immense potential, please do not stop updating it. EDIT: I should note that the demo on your site doesn't work properly, for example, when I hover over a few paragraphs, the + button doesn't appear. Using latest Firefox.

Comment: Hi Christine, the should work with most themes when you add some custom CSS. For now, you cannot reply to a comment (that's definitely a future feature). "Inline Comments for editors/admins" is a great idea and on my to-do list now.

Comment: "This plugin has been closed as of December 16, 2018 and is not available for download. This closure is permanent. Reason: Author Request."

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, but I don’t know a plugin.

How it could be done *(for the lazy web):*

- Add an `id` automatically to every paragraph, table, list or image.
- Insert a small icon per Javascript after each element with an `id` to indicate that one can add comments. Maybe a counter for existing comments too.
- On click move the comment form beneath the element to comment (like the native reply-script does it). Create a hidden custom comment field `relates_to` with the `id` as a value.
- On submit save the custom field.
- During the page output collect the comments for each element and place them wherever they should appear.

Answer (score 2):

Livefyre Sidenotes plugin for WordPress does exactly this:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/livefyre-sidenotes/

[image: Livefyre Sidenotes inline commenting system]

It enables contextual inline commenting not only per paragraph, but, within this, commenting on a particular section highlighted by the user, which would be *closer to the MS Word implementation*:

Start by highlighting the text:

[image: Highlighting]

When the comment has been posted, the highlighted selection is shown upon hovering over the comment posted:

[image: Commenting on highlighted text - like Word]

I'd also been looking for a plugin to do this for quite some time, for an articles discussion site. I had come across a few, but held off implementing one due to uncertainties regarding [possible error or incompatibility](http://wptavern.com/medium-style-commenting-plugins-for-wordpress-highlight-difficulty-in-theme-compatibility) either now or in the future. Although there is a downside from the point of view of data portability (presumably, the comments would be tied down to the Livefyre service), I would personally go with this solution, given that a company devoted to commenting systems is behind it as a guarantor and support for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Does this require the Livefyre commenting system to be installed?

Comment: @ChristineCooper: it only requires the [Livefyre Sidenotes plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/livefyre-sidenotes/), which is separate from the other WP plugin from Livefyre, [Livefyre Comments](https://wordpress.org/plugins/livefyre-comments/). You do need to have or create an account with Livefyre to use it, though.